# MYSQL : looping dates from specified date till today

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement wherein I cannot create any new procedure or modify existing any current one's in MySql.I need to write the code where all the dates are published in the respective pattern(specified below) within a date range.For this, I tried all the loops but couldn't figure it out.Here's what is wrote :

### Code Start

SET @Startdate = '2016-03-10';

WHILE @Startdate < CURDATE() DO

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%Y%m%e') DateID,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%e/%m/%Y') DDFulldate,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%m/%d/%Y') MMFullDate,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%d') DAY_OFMONTH,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%W') DAY_NAM,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%w') DAY_OFWEEK,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%b') MONTH_NAME,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%M') MonthFullName,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%c') MONTH_NUMBER,
QUARTER(@Startdate) QUARTER_NAME,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%Y') YEAR_NAME,
DATE_FORMAT(@Startdate,'%m%Y') MonthYear

SET @Startdate =DATE_ADD(@Startdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);

END WHILE;
```

### Code End

Desired result set has been attached.[Desired Sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjC7Q.png)

Comment: why would you do that in mysql?

Comment: have a limitation of using MySql